# jstl fn:length tag not working inside spring form tag in a jsp

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

inside a "form:form"

```
<form:form class="form-container" name ="feedback_popup_form" id="feedback_popup_form"    action="savefeedback" method="post" modelAttribute="feedbackVO" commandName="feedbackVO">

<form:input type="hidden" path="strEmplRefrlSeq" value="${model.strEmplRefrlSeq}" />

<input type="hidden" id="mady" value = "${fn:length(model.strEmplRefrlSeq)}" />
```

in firebug i am getting

```
<input id="strEmplRefrlSeq" type="hidden" value="2,10,11," name="strEmplRefrlSeq">
<input id="mady" type="hidden" value="0">
```

my fn:length is not working for string input. could you please explain why this is happening ?

Comment: what's the model.strEmplRefrlSeq type？ string ?

Comment: Please show us the actual code. There is no way that `<input type="hidden" path="strEmplRefrlSeq" value="${model.strEmplRefrlSeq}" />` becomes `<input id="strEmplRefrlSeq" type="hidden" value="2,10,11," name="strEmplRefrlSeq">`. Where would the name attribute come from? Why would the path attribute (which is not valid HTML BTW) disappear?

Comment: as mentioned above it is inside form:form jstl tag which converts path into id and name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form backing object is placed under the name "feedbackVO", so I guess you actually need

```
<input type="hidden" id="mady" value="${fn:length(feedbackVO.strEmplRefrlSeq)}" />
```

Note that the form:input tag doesn't have any value attribute, so your code is equivalent to:

```
<form:input type="hidden" path="strEmplRefrlSeq" />
```

which generates the HTML's input value attribute from the path, fetching the value in the command object.

Comment: that is the form value object i'm going to submit

Comment: clearly you could see the value(2,10,11) is going into the input in firebug

Comment: What I mean is that `value` is not a valid attribute of the `<form:input>` tag. See the tag reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#spring-form.tld.input. There is no value attribute listed.

Comment: you were exactly ri8 i'm so sorry the value was coming because of the commandName.Thanks a ton, good luck.